# printw plus scanf in ncurse window won't display typed text

Tags: c, ncurses

I got this portion of my program that prints something on the screen indefinitely until the user hits the spacebar and enter some value. I tried calling echo() right before the first printw but it didn't work. Can anyone tell me why when typing, the price doesn't get displayed on the screen or at least point me to the right place? I also initially used scanw but it won't interrupt the loop and some random values are already being retrieved for the price.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ncurses.h>


int kbhit(void){
    int ch = getch();
    if (ch != ERR) {
        ungetch(ch);
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    echo();
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    scrollok(stdscr, TRUE);
    int price;

    while(1){
        printw("sleeping...\n");
        refresh();
        if (kbhit()) {
            char c = getch();
            switch (c){
                case 32:
                    printw("\nPrice in USD? ");
                    refresh();
                    scanf("%d", &price);
                    printw("\nPrice entered: %d\n",price);
                    refresh();
                    break;
            }
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you debug a little to narrow the problem to either the `getch()` thing in `kbhit()` or the `scanf()` in the `while()` ?

Comment: The problem when I use scanw is that it takes whatever the value of price variable right away without waiting for user's input. So it would be random value if I don't initialize it. Does anyone else have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't *work* because **`scanf`** reads from the standard input, which is put into *raw mode* by ncurses (actually any curses library).  You probably meant [**`scanw`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_scanw.3x.html), which reads the input using the ncurses library.

Answer (score 0):

Setting nodelay to FALSE and calling echo() before the first printw allowed me to use scanw. I just had to set them back to noecho() and nodelay=TRUE right after scanw and everything works fine as expected. Thanks everyone!

```
case 32:
       nodelay(stdscr, FALSE);
       echo();
       printw("\nPrice in USD? ");
       refresh();
       scanw("%d", &price);
       nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
       noecho();
       printw("Price entered: %d\n",price);
       refresh();
       break;
```